# Plotting array to Google stack bar

Tags: php, arrays, bar-chart, google-visualization

I am having hard time here manipulating my array to fit the stack bar, I am using google stack bar API [here](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#bar_chart)
 basically I have array like this :

```
Array ( [A] => Array ( 
                  [0] => 1 
                  [1] => 5 
                  [2] => 5 ) 
        [B] => Array ( 
                  [0] => 3  
                  [1] => 5 
                  [2] => 5 )
        [C] => Array ( 
                  [0] => 2 
                  [1] => 3
                  [2] => 5 ) )
```

I want my stack bar to be like this

[image]

sadly I cant manipulate my array, the letters are ITEMS I need to count how many rate are equal to 5, or 2, etc. I need to have an array like this

```
Array ([A]=> Array ([1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 2 ) 
[B]=> Array ([1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [5] => 2 ) 
[C]=> Array ([1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [5] => 1 ))
```

could anyone help me , many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your data to end up in the following format:

```
Series  1   2   3   4   5
a       #   #   #   #   #
b       #   #   #   #   #
c       #   #   #   #   #
```

If you get your data in to that format, the following code will recreate the chart you have:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rate 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rate 2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rate 3');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rate 4');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rate 5');
  data.addRows([
    ['a', 1, null, null, null, 2],
    ['b', null, null, 1, null, 2],
    ['c', null, 1, 1, null, 1]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups"},
            isStacked: true}
      );
}
```

If your issue is just how to manipulate the array, that's a totally different cup of tea, and you'll have to be a bit more clear about what your requirements are (what language are you using, what limitations if any are there, how big is the actual data set, etc.).